# Here-API load 'NextPageInformation'

Tags: json, here-api

I've been getting my feet wet with the HERE.com API, and I can't seem to figure out how to load the next page of information. I was exploring the following part of the api:

```
https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode
```

I increased the radius to 1000m and set maxresults=100 (that's as high as it goes).

```
https://reverse.geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8839%2C-87.6389%2C1000&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=100&gen=8&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg
```

Now i didn't expect it to load ever address in a 1000m radius. I wanted to see how to load the next 100 results, or the next page. I saw the following at the top of the JSON output and thought, that I could somehow go to page 2. I feel really dumb that I don't see a way to specify a parameter to do that or a way to continue loading results.

```
"MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2016-04-16T17:35:51.493+0000",
      "NextPageInformation": "2"
}
```

Here's a larger excerpt of the JSON that was returned:

```
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2016-04-16T17:35:51.493+0000",
      "NextPageInformation": "2"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 1,
            "Distance": 16.3,
            "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "Country": 1,
              "State": 1,
              "County": 1,
              "City": 1,
              "District": 1,
              "Street": [
                1
              ],
              "HouseNumber": 1,
              "PostalCode": 1
            },
            "MatchType": "pointAddress",
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_puy2gbuVuGd-an6zGdSyNA_xADM",
              "LocationType": "address",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 41.88403,
                "Longitude": -87.63881
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at their docs and there seems to be a parameter "pageinformation" you can add to the URL. Not sure if it works but you might give it a try.

> A key which identifies the page to be returned when the response is separated into multiple pages

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html